# Ubuntu 22.04 Browsers not saving files to attached Google drive?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, online-accounts

Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop
Added Google Drive under settings > Online Accounts.
Using any browser, FireFox or Google Chrome, I am not able to save files to my network Google drive.

**What happens:** When saving a file from browser, the save dialog just goes away and nothing is saved to the drive.

**I've noticed:**
This happens on all of my devices using Ubuntu 22.04. This does not happen on other systems running other OS, works on Mac OSX, and Windows 10.

**What I've done**

- Made sure I have Gnome enabled in my Google account security
  settings.
- System is up to date
- Tried installing Flatpak versions of the browsers
- Tried disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Found this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1971168